# C# Detect mac M1 cpu programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I have to implement different logic between normal(?) mac cpu and m1 cpu.

But I don't know how can I detect that.

Comment: I looked for a Mono solution for you, but it doesn't seem like Mono is compatible with the M1 CPUs anyway.

Comment: Is `System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSArchitecture` good enough?

Comment: @Lesiak Arm64 doesn't mean m1. Isn't it?

Comment: @HenryLee going forwards no. But per the Arm license you should only care about the AArch64 version and not anything else. The vendor is required to hide anything not officially in the ABI. For MacOS you should really only care if it's ARM64 or not.

Answer (score 3):

Under the assumption that M1 is the only arm64 chip that runs OSX then you can use:

```
var isArm = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture == Architecture.Arm64;
var isOSX = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX);
var isM1 = isArm && isOSX;
```